# Cant override controllerDidChangeContent in NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift4

Greetings citizens of Stack,
When trying to override "controllerDidChangeContent" I get "Method does not override any method from its superclass". The stub is produced by the autocompletion handler and it seems to match the requirements of [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller). Code follows:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

  class ViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{
  var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<People>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
       let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

       let request: NSFetchRequest<People> = People.fetchRequest()
       request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true )]

       frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request,
                                     managedObjectContext: context,
                                     sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                     cacheName: nil)

       }

   override func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller:  NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
       print(controller.description)
   }
}
```

The error is produced by the override code. I put the print() in there as filler. THX

Comment: Remove 'override'. Also, not sure why frc is declared outside class.

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to put that outside. fixed. You have the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `override`.

You are implementing the protocol, not overriding.